# Socks and drawers

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, sampling

We have an infinite amount of sock drawers, and in each of them there are K different socks (but the set of socks in every drawer is the same). We are taking out socks randomly from the drawers one-by-one. What is the average amount of drawers we need to open to collect the whole set of K socks?

Comment: Instance of [Coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: Does each drawer can be open only once?

Comment: Yup. @drhab gave the correct answer